# Highlighting a text from the document getting duplicate adds

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am new to `angular js`. Here, I have a string

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged
```

Now, Here I am trying to highlight a text from the document Now, The problem is like ->

In this text I have highlighted Lorem Ipsum has been by adding some span class . Now, for the next interation, if the startoffset and endoffset has a string which is nothing but Ipsum has been the industry's standard . Now, Here there will be overlapping of these two and then the highlighting is overlapping . So, I am not able get the exact text, because of that the offsets gets changed.

Now, For this I tried the following solution ->

```
const str = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged';

const highlights = [{startOffset: 2, endOffset: 16}, {startOffset: 68, endOffset: 75}, {startOffset: 80, endOffset: 92}];

const result = [];
let currentIndex = 0;

highlights.forEach(h => {
  result.push(str.substring(currentIndex, h.startOffset));
  result.push(`<span class="mark">${str.substring(h.startOffset, h.endOffset)}</span>`);
  currentIndex = h.endOffset;
});

result.push(str.substring(currentIndex, str.length));

document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = result.join('')
```

Now, In this,It is solving my issue but Here A duplicate text is getting added in my string , if it is overlapping then. There if there is a text which is overlapping one another then it is seperating the text. But I don't want that kind of behaviour.can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Are you trying to create something similar to richtext editor ?

Comment: No, Its not like that. It's like, I have some text from that text I wan to highlight some part of text which is coming from backend to me. And then there if some part which needs to be highlighted is also a part of some another text which is already highlighted .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand your question correctly, but your problem occures, if the highlighted areas overlap, like this?

```
var highlights = [{startOffset: 2, endOffset: 16}, 
                  {startOffset: 85, endOffset: 100}, 
                  {startOffset: 80, endOffset: 92}];
```

For that to work, you must first produce distinct areas.

```
highlights.sort(function (a, b) {return a.startOffset - b.startOffset; }); //first order by the start offset
// highlights looks like this
//[{startOffset: 2, endOffset: 16},
// {startOffset: 80, endOffset: 92},
// {startOffset: 85, endOffset: 100}]

// next merge all overlapping areas

for(var i = 0; i < highlights.length - 1; i++) { //each element but the last, because it can't overlap with the next
    if(highlights[i].endOffset > highlights[i + 1].startOffset) { //if it overlaps with the next
        highlights[i].endOffset = highlights[i].endOffset > highlights[i + 1].endOffset ? 
            highlights[i].endOffset : highlights[i + 1].endOffset; //take the higher end offset of those two as new offset

        highlights.splice(i + 1, 1); //remove next element in list, since it is no longer useful
        i--; //check current element again
    }
}
//output
//[{startOffset: 2, endOffset: 16},
// {startOffset: 80, endOffset: 100}]
```

After that, your code should work.

Comment: the basic idea is to reduce the highlight array to distinct areas which should be highlighted.   

this is done by finding overlapping areas (if a area ends after the next starts, it overlaps)
if it overlaps, take the first start value and the last end value (the conditional assignment)
at last, remove the now unused highlight area (it was unioned into the first)

Comment: But here, I want to highlight both the things like overlapped as well.

Comment: I tried this but it is now not working for the overlapped things